# Логический повтор с местоимением

Tags: грамматика, основа

Подскажите, какая грамматическая основа в предложении и почему:

> Когда слышен писк, это шумит кот.

Answer (score 1):

***Когда слышен писк, это шумит кот.***

1. Это сложноподчиненное предложение СПП (с придаточным времени или условия, здесь эти значения сближены). Соответственно, здесь две основы: ***слышен писк*** и ***шумит кот***. Предложение нестандартное, скорее из области фразеологии.
2. Вызывает интерес основа главной части, так как не очень ясно **значение местоимения** "это". В данном случае «это» – указательное слово, в основу оно напрямую не входит, а относится ко всему предложению.

Из словаря: 2. ЭТО. I. 2. Употр. как указательное слово на границе двух предложений, из которых второе является объяснением, истолкованием первого. Рентген был известный физик, это он открыл гамма-излучение.

Местоимение «это» во второй части отсылает нас к содержанию первой части (такие элементы называют анафорическими). Примечание. Анафора – греч. аnaphora, букв. перенос вверх, то есть к началу предложения.

3. Перед «это» можно поставить тире, если есть желание обозначить паузу, но запятая тоже возможна.

**У Розенталя** предложения такой конструкции рассматриваются в разделе «Тире в сложноподчинённом предложении», пункт 2(3), там он говорит об условиях, **благоприятствующих** постановке тире  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

Наличие слов ***это, вот***. Что она натура честная — **это** мне ясно (Т.); Когда муха назойливо вьётся перед вашими глазами — **это** неприятно…