# Пунктуация при уточнении с повтором и местоимением

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли поставлены знаки в предложениях?

> Когда они прыгают, - это я люблю.
> Когда слышен писк, это шумит кот.

Answer (score 1):

(1) **Когда они прыгают, — это я люблю.** (2) **Когда слышен писк, это шумит кот.**

Оба варианта в принципе допустимы, это одна и та же грамматика. Но оформление этих предложений встречается разное: только запятая, только тире, запятая и тире.

1. **Только тире**
   *Что она натура честная — это мне ясно* (Т.); *Когда муха назойливо вьётся перед вашими глазами — это неприятно…*

По Розенталю указательное местоимение ЭТО способствует использованию тире, но не требует его обязательной постановки. Выбор варианта (запятая или тире) зависит от наличия **паузы.**
Розенталь: «Тире в сложноподчинённом предложении», пункт 2(3). http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

2. **Только запятая** (примеры из Нацкорпуса с запятой):

*А когда делаешь что-либо с радостью, это всегда сказывается на результатах*. [И. К. Архипова. Музыка жизни (1996)] *Если всё было тихо, это всегда означало плохое...* [И. Грекова. Под фонарем (1963)]

3. **Запятая и тире**

В качестве единого знака запятая и тире ставится как в СПП, так и в БСП. В этом случае единый знак подчеркивает деление предложение **на две смысловые части** и обозначает **подчеркнутую**  паузу.

Пусть я даже ошибаюсь, — что ж, ошибаться свойственно человеку. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144

4. В то же время в нераспространенных предложениях и **без особой надобности** этот знак не стоит использовать и лучше обойтись одним тире или запятой: *Когда они прыгают — это я люблю. Когда они прыгают, это я люблю.*
5. **Примечание**. Грамматика подобных предложений рассматривается в другом ответе. [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470859/Логический-повтор-с-местоимением](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470859/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Comment: Sharon, вы оставили запятую перед тире в первом предложении, а потом пишете о выборе между запятой и тире. Я думаю, вы просто скопировали из вопроса и не обратили внимания? Если это не так, тогда нужно изменить объяснения.

Comment: Спасибо вам за замечания, я исправила ответ по возможности. Признаться, я бы с большим удовольствием удалила бы его. От этих вопросов, на которые никто не хочет отвечать, обычно  одни неприятности. :)